# Codeigniter - downloading file with use of force_download function

Tags: codeigniter, download

I'm using Latest CI. I have not any problem while working in local. But when i move my works to live server, i'm facing a problem.

When i download files from my download tab, File is getting download with correct size and format. But when i open that downloaded file, for ex, if it is an image, image is not displaying , or if it is word, it's asking for selecting encode type and after selecting encode type , content is junk characters.

How to solve this issue.?

Thanks in advance.

Code I used to download file:

```
$content = file_get_contents($file_loc);
force_download(FILENAME.EXT, $content);
```

Comment: Added code at the bottom of question

Comment: It sounds like a web server configuration problem... what webserver are you running locally and on live?

Comment: what is wrong with you using force_download(path, NULL, true) ? . Don't explicitly read the file contents before download. Let the helper handle that for you. Except the file you are trying to download hasn't an extension

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.

```
ob_clean(); 
$data = file_get_contents("localhost/qlip/uploads/filename.jpg"); //assuming my file is on localhost
$name = 'document.jpg'; 
force_download($name,$data);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code follow:

```
<?php

function downloadFile($file){
   $file_name = $file;
   $mime = 'application/force-download';
   header('Pragma: public');    
   header('Expires: 0');        
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
   header('Cache-Control: private',false);
   header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Connection: close');
   readfile($file_name);    
   exit();
}
?>
```

and call function :

```
<?php
downloadFile("./files/image.jpg");
?>
```

provided that the file "image.jpg" is the correct address

Comment: No. It's not working. It again shows the same error after downloading.

Finally I decided to give the link to full url of that file.

Comment: I've tried to put it in the helper. then call that function in the controller and it worked. Do not forget to load the helper.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer, you could try this:

```
function download() 
{
    // asumming you have http://www.domain.com/index.php/controller/download/file_name/extension/
    $extension = $this->uri->segment(4); // file extension
    $file_name = $this->uri->segment(3) . '.' . $extension; // file name
    $file_path = FCPATH . 'application/documentos/' . $file_name; // absolute path to file
    if (is_file($file_path)) {
        $mime = 'application/force-download';
        header('Pragma: public');    
        header('Expires: 0');        
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Cache-Control: private',false);
        header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file_name . '"'); file name
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Connection: close');
        readfile(base_url() . 'application/documentos/' . $file_name); // relative path to file   
        exit();
    } else {
        redirect('/welcome/');
    }
}
```

Comment: don't try to rewrite your own download helper unless the current one doesn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

Add ob_clean(); before the code of force_download(); else the image,word file get corrupted.

```
ob_clean();
$content = file_get_contents($file_loc);
force_download(FILENAME.EXT, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

in CI 3 : works for me

```
 $data = 'Here is some text!';
 $name = 'mytext.txt';
 force_download($name, $data);
```

or :

```
 // Contents of photo.jpg will be automatically read
 force_download('/path/to/photo.jpg', NULL);
```

[source](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

your file path is incorrect. fix path to correct and run.it should work.