# File download error when file has no content or size is 0

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, download

I am unable to download any file(text,doc or any other extention) if its size is 0 byte or it has nothing written inside. Here is the code I am using as follows.

```
$filename = $this->input->get('filename');              
$fileoriginalname = $this->input->get('fileorgname');

$this->load->helper('download');
$Path = 'files/'.$filename;
$data = file_get_contents($Path);

force_download($fileoriginalname, $data);
```

Can anyone help me to solve it. The above code is working fine if the file has any content inside but stop working if nothing is there so I am very confused and somehow frustrated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by unable? Is there an error of some sort? Is `file_get_contents` returning false?

Comment: There is no error but page are being blank and unable to download the file. And `file_get_contents` is returning true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this problem also but somehow I got help from [File Size Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452440/codeigniter-downloading-file-with-use-of-force-download-function)

You can use this following code and see if it helps.

Instead of using `force_download` try this

```
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')) 
  { 
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); 
  }


    $this->load->helper('file');

    $mime = get_mime_by_extension($Path);


    header('Pragma: public');     // required
    header('Expires: 0');         // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($Path)).' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private',false);
    header('Content-Type: '.$mime);  
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileoriginalname.'"');  // Add the file name
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($Path)); 
    header('Connection: close');
    readfile($Path); 
    exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, not being able to see the rest of the code.

I am assuming that when you are trying to download a file of 0bytes, an error is occurring

so i would maybe write something like

```
if(!force_download($fileoriginalname, $data))
{
    \\ the file download failed. handle this error
}
```

Comment: Yes I did that and I am getting that error message, Thanks but that is not my question but how to solve it and download a 0 byte file.